# Largest Rectangle in Histogram in Rust

Tags: algorithm, rust

Whilst learning Rust I am solving different algorithm problems. Below is a solution to largest rectangle in histogram.
Algorithm is well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311694/maximize-the-rectangular-area-under-histogram):

Although code below does the job it is very verbose (much more than my C++ solution).

```
pub fn largest_rectangle(v: &mut Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let mut stack: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
    // populate stack with 0 - (index of first element in 'v') to avoid checking for empty stack
    stack.push(0);
    // insert -1 from both sides so that we don't have to test for corner cases
    v.insert(0, -1);
    v.push(-1);
    let mut answer = 0;
    for (i, h) in v.iter().enumerate() {
        let idx = i as i32;
        if h > &v[stack.last().unwrap().clone()] {
            stack.push(i);
        } else {
            while h < &v[stack.last().unwrap().clone()] {
                let last_bar = v[stack.pop().unwrap().clone()];
                let area = last_bar * (idx - 1 - stack.last().unwrap().clone() as i32);
                answer = std::cmp::max(area, answer);
            }
            stack.push(i);
        }
    }
    answer
}
```

My questions:

1. Is it possible to get rid of those 'unwrap().clone()' constructs?
2. Why does compiler make me use references in if statements (h > &v[] and h < &v[])?